# Guttag - Python Exercise Fib

Tags: python

New to writing code in Python and I am trying to attempt the finger exercise on page 54 on implementation of fib in the code below that is used to compute fib(5) and asking how many times the value of fib(2) is computed on the way to computing fib(5)?

```
def fib(x):
"""Assumes n int >= 0
    Returns Fibonacci of n"""
if n == 0 or n == 1:
    return 1
else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def testFib(n):
for i in range(n+1):
    print('fib of' , i, '=' , fib(i))
x=5
```

I added x=5 at the end.  What am I missing in trying to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `x` at all.  Note that your function definition uses a parameter named `x` but then refers to `n` inside the body of the function.  They should match.

To answer the question of how many times `fib(2)` is called, you probably want to do something like add logging inside `fib`:

```
def fib(n: int) -> int:
    """Assumes n >= 0
    Returns Fibonacci of n"""
    if n == 2:
        print("called fib(2)")
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print(f"fib(5) = {fib(5)}")
```

```
called fib(2)
called fib(2)
called fib(2)
fib(5) = 8
```

Comment: Thank you, Samwise.  I see the two differences in code added from what I have.  In thinking your response through on the logic within the formula, I am assuming that the print(f"fib(5) = {fib(5)}') at the end identify that we are computing fib(5) and that if n = =2 asks how many times fib (2) is computed?

Comment: Yes, `fib(5)` computes `fib(5)`, no magic there.  :)  The `if n == 2` means we'll print the thing on the next line if `n` is 2 (which it will be any time *anything* has called `fib(2)`).